# Java working environment when having to use native code

Tags: java, netbeans, jvm, native, environment

I often have to depend on third-party native libraries to work in conjunction with my Java code. I wonder, is there anyone out there that can share their best practices in working in such an environment. I'm running Snow Leopard and I typically use Netbeans for my IDE needs. So how about it...do you put your native libraries into a ./lib folder in your project and pass arguments to the JVM? Do you put them in your home directory and pass arguments into the netbeans config files? other?

thanks in advance!
jagwire

Answer (score 1):

Java has a technique to call native libraries. It is called Java Native Interface (JNI).

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate a bit more on how to use it, to fill out the answer?

Comment: I am on mobile. Will do it when I get home or feel free to post your own answer.

Comment: It's not so much using the JNI that I'm thinking about, but more the workflow of including the JAR,JNILIB(s) couple into your project workflow for efficiency, but thanks for the quick response!

Comment: I am not sure about NetBeans, but in Eclipse it is possible to seamlessly integrate everything.